# Cassandra full table dump to HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use the Spark-Cassandra connector from Datastax (v2.0.2, Spark v2.0.0) :

```
val df = sparkSession.sparkContext.cassandraTable[MyRec](keyspace, tableName).toDF()
df.write.format("orc").save(hdfsLocation)
```

It looks pretty straightforward and worked fine for a while but I started to get such exceptions:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException:
  Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 
responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
...
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$
spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(
CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:342)
```

Increasing `spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms` and `spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms` and
decreasing `spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows` didn't help. Also played with the read consistency level.

I did a major compaction on the table and it didn't help. 
Since this is a prod. DB I can't adjust server side parameters like
`tombstone_failure_threshold` as suggested [here](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204612559-ReadTimeoutException-seen-when-using-the-java-driver-caused-by-excessive-tombstones).

What's the most efficient way to load full tables from Cassandra (v3.7.0) to HDFS (Hive)?

Comment: I think the problem here is on Cassandra side, not on Spark, maybe this is what you are facing: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/ZKyACqzoBw4

Comment: Thx for the link.I agree that it's a Cassandra issue, most probably because of the tombstones. Is there any way to still do full dump and avoid such a problem? Would a MR job using CqlInputFormat more performant?

Comment: Do you know the vendors for C* and Hive? (Apache/HDP/CDH)

Comment: @saitejalakkimsetty Apache Cassandra and HDP 2.5.3

Comment: @Bruckwald, like @RussS suggested, this is a temporary availability problem due to peak load which means that the query/jobs is not scaling well. In production environments, actions involving streaming/querying whole table is an anti-pattern (C*).

There are many ways to solve this problem.
You can dump the C* table in steps by giving a `CQL` query as ` select * from test_table where token(PK) > (sometoken);`
You can fiddle with read timeouts and retries.

An alternative, scalable solution is to create a streaming process with Kafka as that is already included in HDP.

Comment: @Bruckwald, You can use Flume to sink data into Kafka and use Spark to read from Kafka and dump it into HDFS. Here is a good startpoint from the [spark-cassandra-connector] (https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best you can do if it is availability issues is to increase the number of retries `spark.cassandra.query.retry.count`

and lower the pages per read threshold

`spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows`

Basically, if this is coming up in the middle of the load than the problem is that the Cassandra node is being overloaded so lowering the throughput is the only way to solve this issue.

Another option is to lower the number of executor cores `spark.cores.max` which would also lower throughput.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Can you please name these parameters?
"Cassandra node is being overloaded" Does this mean that I can run into this issue if  there are lot of tombstones / compaction tasks running on a different keyspace?

Comment: I added the parameter names. Overloading a C* node can come from lots of background tasks or simply two many simultaneous requests (which is why limiting the number of executor cores can help). Another solution is to increase your RF so that requests have more viable targets for reads, this would increase the potential throughput of your cluster.